# Word2vec Vector Quality vs Number of Training Iterations

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, word2vec

I was looking at this paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.07891v1.pdf and at one point it states

`When training the local models, we sampled
1000 documents from p(d) with replacement.
To compensate for the much smaller corpus
size, we ran word2vec training for 80 iterations.`

Does this mean that if your corpus is too small to produce good word vectors, you can just bump up the number of training iterations and the quality would improve?

Comment: good question! would love to hear answers from experts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically when a deep learning neural network runs, you want to optimize the weights on each neuron *given the data and model*. These "ideal weights" are very hard to compute exactly, so instead you run gradient descent to update the weights some on each iteration and get a good approximation.

The more iterations you do, the better your performance, but you're never going to do better than your model+data would with an optimal choice of weights.

So yes, you can improve the performance of Word2Vec some by increasing the number of iterations. But in practice, I haven't seen much gain beyond 20-30 iterations, and there's a hard upper bound on performance imposed by the quality and quantity of data you have.